# Equalize widths of columns across two tabular environments

Tags: tables

I'm making a list of verbs but I can't align the first table I made with the single row table I made. The idea is to align the vertical lines. (See image below.)

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}

\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{tikz,efbox}
\usepackage[left=1cm,right=1cm,top=1cm,bottom=2cm]{geometry}

\efboxsetup{linecolor=black!100, linewidth=0.22pt, margin=0pt}

\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage[contents={},opacity=0]{background}

\definecolor{titlegrammar}{RGB}{255,128,0}
\definecolor{fucsia}{RGB}{196,0,98}
\definecolor{fucsia2}{RGB}{246,150,235}

\usepackage{XCharter}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\begin{document}
text
\clearpage
\backgroundsetup{position={0,0},opacity=0.15,placement=bottom,angle=0,scale=1,contents={\begin{tikzpicture}
    \fill[fucsia] (0cm,0cm) rectangle (\paperwidth,\paperheight);
  \filldraw[help lines,step=1.2mm,line width=0.8pt,white]      (0cm,0cm) grid (\paperwidth,\paperheight);
    \end{tikzpicture}}
}
%\BgThispage
%\arrayrulewidth=0.67pt
\efbox{\begin{tabular}{|l|l|l|}
\hline
\rowcolor{fucsia2}\textbf{Base form} & \textbf{Past simple} & \textbf{Past participle} \\
\hline
\rowcolor{white}be & was/were & been \\
\hline
\rowcolor{white}become & became & become \\
\hline
\rowcolor{white}begin & began & begun \\
\hline
\rowcolor{white}bend & bent & bent \\
\hline
\rowcolor{white}bite & bit & bitten \\
\hline
\rowcolor{white}blow & blew & blown \\
\hline
\rowcolor{white}break & broke & broken \\
\hline
\rowcolor{white}bring & brought & brought \\
\hline
\rowcolor{white}build & built & built \\
\hline
\rowcolor{white}burn & burned/burnt & burned/burnt \\
\hline
\rowcolor{white}buy & bought & bought \\
\hline
\end{tabular}}

\vspace{2ex}
\efbox{\begin{tabular}{|l|l|l|}
\rowcolor{white}learn & learned / learnt & learned / learnt
\end{tabular}}
\clearpage
\backgroundsetup{opacity=0}
text

\end{document}
```

[image]

I also understand that the renderisation of the tables is not properly done, but that's not an issue because I often convert the pages into JPEG images and the that problem is solved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The width of a column of type `l` is given by the widest element in the `tabular` environment. If the widest elements in two columns of type `l` across two separate `tabular` environments aren't equally wide, the column widths will differ as well.

I suggest you replace both instances of

```
\begin{tabular}{|l|l|l|}
```

with

```
\begin{tabular}{|p{2.5cm}|p{2.5cm}|p{2.5cm}|}
```

As you can guess, the argument of the `p` column type determines the width.

Answer (score 1):

Use for both the tables the header:

```
\begin{tabular}{|p{5em}|p{7em}|p{7em}|}
```

Here is the relevant part of the code:

```
\efbox{\begin{tabular}{|p{5em}|p{7em}|p{7em}|}
\hline
\rowcolor{fucsia2}\textbf{Base form} & \textbf{Past simple} & \textbf{Past participle} \\
\hline
\rowcolor{white}be & was/were & been \\
\hline
\rowcolor{white}become & became & become \\
\hline
\rowcolor{white}begin & began & begun \\
\hline
\rowcolor{white}bend & bent & bent \\
\hline
\rowcolor{white}bite & bit & bitten \\
\hline
\rowcolor{white}blow & blew & blown \\
\hline
\rowcolor{white}break & broke & broken \\
\hline
\rowcolor{white}bring & brought & brought \\
\hline
\rowcolor{white}build & built & built \\
\hline
\rowcolor{white}burn & burned/burnt & burned/burnt \\
\hline
\rowcolor{white}buy & bought & bought \\
\hline
\end{tabular}}

\vspace{2ex}
\efbox{\begin{tabular}{|p{5em}|p{7em}|p{7em}|}
\rowcolor{white}learn & learned/ learnt & learned / learnt
\end{tabular}}
```

[image]